# Calling iFrame from HTTPS

Tags: http, iis, iframe, https

I have a code that I save on an iis site on my server.

I want to approach it using iFrame from 2 other hosts.

It works from one host but not from the other one.

It works fine from a host that starts with HTTP but not from the one that starts with HTTPS.

I added the "HTTP Response Header" properties with name: Content-Security-Policy and value: "frame-ancestors http://www.rabincenter.org.il https://www.rosh-hanikra.com; form-action 'self' http://www.rabincenter.org.il https://www.rosh-hanikra.com".

The iFrame that does not work displays the error message: "myCode sent an invalid response.".

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone give me a hand?

Thank you in advance

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use F12 develop console network tab to see actually response staus codes and error message.

Comment: I tried that but since my client creates his web pages with WordPress I cannot see the error on the client's side.